# php excel trying to add sheets with data dynamically in one workbook

Tags: php, excel

I am trying to write the data to the multiple sheets in one excel file using phpExcel. I am getting data as array and i am looping it in that i am creating and writing the data .Problem is that it is creating the multiple sheets but it is writing all the data in one sheet.  Below is my code:

```
function getcsv($data, $cirval, $opval)
        {
            global $objPHPExcel;

            $myWorkSheet = new PHPExcel_Worksheet($objPHPExcel, $cirval);
            $objPHPExcel->addSheet($myWorkSheet);
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);

            $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();    

            $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Denomination');
            $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Validity');
            $sheet->setCellValue('C1', 'Data Plan');

            $rowcounter = 1;
                foreach($data as $v1){
                    $rowcounter++;
                    $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $rowcounter, $v1['Denomination']);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $rowcounter, $v1['Validity']);
                    $sheet->setCellValue('C' . $rowcounter, $v1['Data Plan']);

                }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
```

When you add a new worksheet using `addSheet()`, then PHPExcel automatically makes that the current active sheet.... you're explicitly overriding that behaviour and resetting the active sheet so that it is always sheet id #1, so it will always write everything to sheet id #1 no matter how many new sheets you add

Comment: Thank you very much also i am trying to save the file to path like $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
   $objWriter->save('3GNew/'.$opval.'.xslx');
it is giving the excel file with filename without any data